# Auto opening excel vba macro, beforeclose and beforesave

Tags: excel, vba

I have an .xlsm file which i want to run the macro automatically when i open it. The current file is saving the file as .xls in a different location with a different name before saving and before closing. However before closing is giving me error and so is the autorun of macro. Here is my code.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False     ' so you can overwrite without warning
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\name\Desktop\testing.xls"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub



    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False     ' so you can overwrite without warning
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\name\Desktop\testing.xls"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWorkbook.save
    End Sub
    End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried replace `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook`?

Comment: just to confirm that your code is in **ThisWorkbook** and not a **Module**?

Comment: What error? What does the error message say? And how have you tried to fix what it tells you is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you can't have events inside another event like that. You have a `Workbook_BeforeSave` and `Workbook_BeforeClose` *inside* your `Workbook_Open`... That won't work, and in any case I'm not sure what it would even mean!

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    ' This won't work:
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
        '...
    End Sub

    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
        '...
    End Sub
End Sub
```

You need to set up your events separately, like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Stuff to do when file opens...
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    'Stuff to do before user saves the file...
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    'Stuff to do before the user closes the file...
End Sub
```

Also, instead of `ActiveWorkbook`, consider using `Me` (or `ThisWorkbook`) to avoid any ambiguity.